# Make only one BestFriend with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have app that can make friends and best-friend Now I wanna each user have only one best friend , so should define another function/ I used flask-sqlalchemy and many-to-many relation ? Any suggestion ? Thanx

> model.py:

```
friends = db.Table('friends',
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
db.Column('friend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)
best_friend = db.Table('best_friend',
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
db.Column('friend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique= True)
   email = db.Column(db.String(50),index=True, unique= True)

    bestfriend = db.relationship('User',
        secondary = best_friend,
        primaryjoin = (best_friend.c.user_id == id),
        secondaryjoin = (best_friend.c.friend_id == id),
        backref = db.backref('best_friend', lazy = 'dynamic'),
        lazy = 'dynamic'
    )
def are_bestfriends(self, user):
        return self.is_bestfriend.filter(best_friend.c.friend_id == user.id).count()> 0

def be_bestfriend(self, user):
         if not self.are_bestfriends(user):
                  self.bestfriend.append(user)
                  user.bestfriend.append(self)
                  return self
```

Comment: If a user can only have one best friend, you probably want to use a one-to-one relationship, not a many-to-many.

Comment: So I search about one-to-one relationship, I should add  uselist=False to bestfriend=db.relationship But when I try it still I could have more than one best friend am I doing it right @dirn

Comment: Your current data structure allows it. You probably want to change that.

Comment: which part I should change can explain it more clear Thanx @dirn

Comment: Take a look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449462. You can add `uselist=False` both to the `relationship` and to the `backref` of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change from a many-to-many relationship to a one-to-one, start by removing the `best_friends` table.

```
friends = db.Table('friends',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('friend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)
```

You then want to add a foreign key to `User` that references another `User`.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique= True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50),index=True, unique= True)

    bestfriend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    bestfriend = db.relationship('User', remote_side=['id'], lazy='dynamic')

    def are_bestfriends(self, user):
        return self.best_friend == user

    def be_bestfriend(self, user):
        if not self.are_bestfriends(user):
            self.bestfriend = user
            user.bestfriend = self 
            return self
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer- Now i want to define a function to unbest friend can you help me or I should ask new question?              def un_bestfriend(self, user):
          if self.are_bestfriends(user):
                  #remove from bestfriend
                  self.is_bestfriend.....(user)
                  user.is_bestfriend.....(self) 
                  return self @dirn

Comment: You just have to set the value to `None`. `self.bestfriend = None` and `user.bestfriend = None`.